# [C++]nested class shows me "does not name a type" error while making chainiterator

Tags: c++, linked-list

trying to make chained list iterator
headerfile(20112310_3.h)

```
#include<iostream>

template<typename T> class Chain;

template<typename T>
class ChainNode{
friend class Chain<T>;
private:
T data;
ChainNode<T> *link;
};

template<typename T>
class Chain{
public:
    Chain();

    class ChainIterator{
        ChainIterator(ChainNode<T> startNode=0);
        T& operator*() const;
        T* operator->() const;
        ChainIterator& operator++();
        ChainIterator operator++(int);
        bool operator!=(const ChainIterator right) const;
        bool operator==(const ChainIterator right) const;
        private:
            ChainNode<T>* current;
    };
private:
    ChainNode<T>* first;
};
```

and here's cpp file(20112310_3.cpp)

```
#include<iostream>
#include "20112310_3.h"

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
Chain<T>::Chain(){first=0;}


template<typename T>
Chain<T>::ChainIterator::ChainIterator(ChainNode<T> startNode){
    current=startNode;
}

template<typename T>
T& Chain<T>::ChainIterator::operator*() const{
    return current->data;
}

template<typename T>
T* Chain<T>::ChainIterator::operator->() const{
    return &current->data;
}

template<typename T>
ChainIterator& Chain<T>::ChainIterator::operator++(){
    current=current->link;
    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
ChainIterator Chain<T>::ChainIterator::operator++(int){
    ChainIterator old=*this;
    current=current->link;
    return old;
}

template<typename T>
bool Chain<T>::ChainIterator::operator!=(const ChainIterator right) const{
    return current!=right.current;
}

template<typename T>
bool Chain<T>::ChainIterator::operator==(const ChainIterator right) const{
    return current==right.current;
}

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

when i try to compile this it gets error

20112310_3.cpp:26:1: error: ‘ChainIterator’ does not name a type
 ChainIterator& Chain::ChainIterator::operator++(){

20112310_3.cpp:32:1: error: ‘ChainIterator’ does not name a type
 ChainIterator Chain::ChainIterator::operator++(int){

how could i resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename T>
ChainIterator& Chain<T>::ChainIterator::operator++() {
```

`ChainIterator` is not in scope yet when it is parsed. You have two solutions -- either qualify the full type:

```
template<typename T>
typename Chain<T>::ChainIterator& Chain<T>::ChainIterator::operator++() {
```

... or use a trailing return type, at which point `ChainIterator` *is* in scope.

```
template<typename T>
auto Chain<T>::ChainIterator::operator++() -> ChainIterator& {
```